# radius of convergence of series having factorial

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Finding radius of convergence of following series $$f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{4^n\cdot n!}{(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$$

What i try : let $\displaystyle a_{n}=\frac{4^n\cdot n!}{(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$. Then $\displaystyle a_{n+1}=\frac{4^{n+1}\cdot (n+1)!}{(2n+3)}x^{2n+3}.$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\bigg|<1$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}4|x^2|\bigg|\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{(2n+3)}\bigg|<1$$

Here the left side quantity is 
$\infty$

I did not understand How can i find radius of convergence. Help me please

Comment: That inequality is only true if $x=0$. Otherwise the series diverges. So the radius is zero.

Comment: Thanks so much David.